# Is there a way to use the python subprocess module's Popen.communicate() without waiting for the process to exit?

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I use Windows XP and Python 2.5. I am trying to make a way for my python programs to secretly communicate with each other, I think the **STARTUPOPTIONS** class could hide the window, but I can't find out how I could communicate with them. On my python subprocess I tried using **raw_input** and on the parent I tried writing to the **Popen.stdin** and flushing it, but it diden't seam to work. I would use **Popen.communicate**, but that waits for the process to exit. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I am going to only make my program available for windows users so if there is a module that is only available for windows, I will not mind it can't run on other Operating Systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/async_subprocess/0.2.1`
"Provides an asynchronous version of Popen.communicate"